# How can I initialise this class in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, juce

I'm trying to make an array of class filePlayerGui and when I try to initialise it in the constructor it won't let me do so

```
class MainComponent   : public Component,
                    public MenuBarModel
{
public:
//==============================================================================
/** Constructor */
MainComponent (Audio& audio_);

/** Destructor */
~MainComponent();

void resized() override;

//MenuBarEnums/Callbacks========================================================
enum Menus
{
    FileMenu=0,

    NumMenus
};

enum FileMenuItems
{
    AudioPrefs = 1,

    NumFileItems
};
StringArray getMenuBarNames() override;
PopupMenu getMenuForIndex (int topLevelMenuIndex, const String& menuName) override;
void menuItemSelected (int menuItemID, int topLevelMenuIndex) override;

private:
Audio& audio;
FilePlayerGui filePlayerGui[2] {audio.getFilePlayer(0), audio.getFilePlayer(1)};



//==============================================================================
JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (MainComponent)
};
```

The filePlayerGui comes up with this error "Copying array element of type 'FilePlayerGui' invokes deleted constructor".  I have tried initialising it in the .cpp file that I'll down below but then it tells me that I need an array initialiser

```
MainComponent::MainComponent (Audio& audio_) : audio (audio_)
{


setSize (500, 400);
addAndMakeVisible(filePlayerGui[0]);
addAndMakeVisible(filePlayerGui[1]);
}

MainComponent::~MainComponent()
{

}

 void MainComponent::resized()
 {
filePlayerGui[0].setBounds (0, 0, getWidth(), 40);
 }

   //MenuBarCallbacks==============================================================
 StringArray MainComponent::getMenuBarNames()
{
const char* const names[] = { "File", 0 };
return StringArray (names);
}

PopupMenu MainComponent::getMenuForIndex (int topLevelMenuIndex, const String& menuName)
{
PopupMenu menu;
if (topLevelMenuIndex == 0)
    menu.addItem(AudioPrefs, "Audio Prefrences", true, false);
return menu;
}

void MainComponent::menuItemSelected (int menuItemID, int topLevelMenuIndex)
{
if (topLevelMenuIndex == FileMenu)
{
    if (menuItemID == AudioPrefs)
    {
        AudioDeviceSelectorComponent audioSettingsComp (audio.getAudioDeviceManager(),
                                                        0, 2, 2, 2, true, true, true, false);
        audioSettingsComp.setSize (450, 350);
        DialogWindow::showModalDialog ("Audio Settings",
                                       &audioSettingsComp, this, Colours::lightgrey, true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of  the `FilePlayerGui`class? I'm sure that it's been declared as non-copyable. The simplest approach is almost certainly going to be to hold pointers to those objects (probably with a JUCE `OwnedArray` object to manage lifetimes for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Copying array element of type `FilePlayerGui` invokes deleted constructor

Means that some variant this line is in the declaration of the `FilePlayerGui`:

```
FilePlayerGui(const FilePlayerGui&) = delete
```

Meaning that a `FilePlayerGui` cannot be copied: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_constructor

There are workarounds, but you are skirting the author of `FilePlayerGui`'s intent for the class. So the correct answer should stop here. Any use of `FilePlayerGui` should be done through the the classes `audio` member, using either: `audio.getFilePlayer(0)` or `audio.getFilePlayer(1)`. (If this is the only member of `MainComponent` in all likelihood `MainComponent` should be eliminated.)

---

If you want to know how to do bad things, which I would reject in any code review, you can either create `filePointerGui` as:

1. `FilePointerGui* filePointerGui[2]` which would be intialized as:

```
MainComponent::MainComponent(Audio& audio_) : audio(audio_), filePointerGui({ &audio.getFilePlayer(0), &audio.getFilePlayer(1) })
```

Access would be performed as:

```
*filePointerGui[0]
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Y934Nh)

2. `reference_wrapper<FilePointerGui> filePointerGui[2]` which would be initialized as:

```
MainComponent::MainComponent(Audio& audio_) : audio(audio_), filePointerGui({ audio.getFilePlayer(0), audio.getFilePlayer(1) })
```

Access would be performed as:

```
filePointerGui[0].get()
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/yhJJZU)

It's probably worth stressing once more this is bad code because it tries to outsmart the language and work around the intent of the classes design. But this is [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) so you *can* do it.

Comment: It comes up with this error "Copying array element of type 'FilePlayerGui' invokes deleted constructor" when I do this

Comment: @harry97uk I've updated my answer, but as you can see from the answer I'm a little salty about it. This isn't a healthy question. You're trying to subvert the intended use of `FilePlayerGui` which almost certainly means that you will continue to run into issues if you proceed down this path.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it has definitely helped me out a lot!  I understand what the problems are but for now I'm going to just create two instances of the class so I can carry on with the work and resolve this issue properly with my university professors, thank you for your help though!

Comment: @harry97uk If this solved your problem I'd suggest accepting the answer. Otherwise writing your own answer and accepting that may be helpful to future readers.